# asp.net mvc duda con la condicional if con llaves y sin llaves " { ... } "

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net, if, condiciones

tengo una duda sobre en que momentos o partes del código se puede usar una condicional `if` u otro que se pueda escribir sin las llaves `{ ... }`.

Por lo que eh leido esto va depender de la cantidad de codigo que contenga esa condicional ejemplo: si tiene una sola linea seria valido usarlo sin llaves en caso de tener n lineas deberia usarse con llaves para encerrar el bloque a ejecutar?

¿Sera así o estoy equivocado?.

Comment: Por lo que sé, al no poner llaves solo leerá como parte del `if` la primera línea siguiente, a partir de ahí todo lo demás estará fuera. Al poner los corchetes le indicas de dónde hasta dónde y, por tanto, que puede tener más de una línea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

estás en lo correcto
Para usar un if sin llaves solamente funciona de la siguiente forma:

```
if("algo")
 //accion que va a realizar
```

Ya que si de lo contrario haces esto:

```
if("algo")
 //Acción a realizar
 //Acción que ya no toma en cuenta
```

Lo que sigue despues de la declaración del if toma solo la siguiente linea, la segunda linea en dado caso ya no la toma dentro del if, para el segundo ejemplo más bien necesitas las llaves, algo así:

```
if("algo"){
  //Todo lo de aquí lo toma en cuenta
  //y esto
  // y así sucesivamente
}
```

A mi gusto es para hacer código más elegante, aunque si usas llaves y solo quieres que tome en cuenta una línea también es valido:

```
if("algo"){
   //Acción en una sola linea
}
```

Comment: Perfecto ! Gracias.